# How badly did I oxidize my beer?

Tags: kegging, racking, oxidation, closed-transfer

I think I oxidized my whole keg. I was attempting a closed transfer but the beer stopped going into the keg so I decided to change the tube but totally forgot about the air in the tube. So when I started to transfer again, bubbles went through the keg. I bled the keg many times right away but I'm not sure how much it helped.

Did you ever have such an experience?  How did it turn out?

Comment: Besides the great answers below, I would add that it gives you a reason to drink it more quickly, and brew another batch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some brewers have a unwarranted paranoia about oxygen and beer. Relax. If there were literally a "few bubbles" in the keg then I very much doubt it will cause the beer to oxidise.

If the beer was not micro-filtered then remaining yeast in solution will use any dissolved oxygen quite quickly.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: Agreed the amount of oxygen in the tube would be minimal at most.

Answer (score 2):

O2 is important to big brewers because the beer will get warm and cold many times and they can't control the age. Drink it fresh and enjoy it. It might not last as long as a super low DO beer like Sierra Nevada but it will be fine in the short run.